# Position Vectors in Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems

So I have a query concerning position vectors and cylindrical coordinates.

In my electromagnetism text(undergrad) there's the following statements for

position vectors in cylindrical coordinates:

$$\vec r = \rho \cos\phi  \hat x + \rho \sin\phi \hat y+z\hat z$$

I understand this statement, it's the following, I don't understand how a 3D position can be expressed thusly:

$$\vec r = \rho \hat \rho + z \hat z$$

Thanks for any insight and help!

Comment: Minor markup detail: `cos\theta` typesets as the product of four symbols ($cos\theta$) while `\cos\theta` typesets as the cosine of theta ($\cos\theta$). Similarly for `\ln`, `\log` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because

$$\hat{\rho}=\cos{\phi}\hat{x}+\sin{\phi}\hat{y}.$$

This is a unit vector in the outward (away from the $z$-axis) direction. Unlike $\hat{z}$, it depends on your azimuthal angle.

The position vector has no component in the tangential $\hat{\phi}$ direction. In cylindrical coordinates, you just go “outward” and then “up or down” to get from the origin to an arbitrary point.